# ANOVA and non-normal data?

Tags: anova, normality-assumption

I am working on a study that is looking at the potential impact the physical environment has on numerous child behaviors.  I have two categories of physical environments that the participates are divided between (different participants in each environment).  There are multiple behaviors that are coded for frequency over a set period of time.  Each behavior is being analyzed separately to see if the different environments have a significant impact on the frequency the behavior occurs.

The original study design was to run a t-test for each behavior.  However when we look at the data it does not follow a bell curve and my (limited) understanding of t-tests is that the data needs to be on a normal curve to have validity.  I am now looking for advice on what analysis would be appropriate to run on this type of data to look for correlation between the environment category and the frequency rate of the behaviors.  Will the ANOVA analysis work or does there need to be another type of analysis?

Comment: What is non-normative data? Please clarify and also add context & details, what are your variables representing, how did you obtain the data, ... please add info as an edit to the post!

Comment: What's the sample size / design?

Comment: There are only 30 total participants (15 for each environment)  Each child was video taped for 30 minutes then the video was coded using 10 second intervals where each behavior was noted that was observed during each interval then the number of times the behavior was noted per video was totaled. This study is meant to look to see if there is enough likelihood that a correlation is present to warrent future studies.